# Eclipse-Photon Ternary Operator Compiling Error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, ternary-operator

The function should compare two integers and print the relation on the screen
althogh,the *ternary operator* is right in syntax and already running on visual studio IDE it gives me an error in eclipse when compiled with gcc:

```
error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
     (x == y) ? c = 61 : (x > y) ? c = 62 : c = 60;
                                              ^
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void _1_6(const int x, const int y)
{
    char c = '\0';
    (x == y) ? c = 61 : (x > y) ? c = 62 : c = 60;
    printf("%d%c%d", x, c, y);
}

int main(void)
{
    _1_6(1, 3);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you format your code properly? Also please copy and paste the error rather than use a screenshot.

Comment: Visual Studio and its compiler is happy to let you do many things that are technically not allowed.

Comment: As I found while formatting, g++ allows that as well. Shared compiler bugs or subtle difference between C  and C++, I don't know.. Did it work? I dunno. Didn't check. A bit more of a deep-dive might be required.

Answer (score 1):

As for *why* you get an error, it's question about [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

The expression is really `((x == y) ? c = 61 : (x > y) ? c = 62 : c) = 60`. That is, you try to assign the value `60` to the expression `(x == y) ? c = 61 : (x > y) ? c = 62 : c` which isn't possible.

You need to either add a few parentheses yourself, like

```
(x == y) ? c = 61 : (x > y) ? c = 62 : (c = 60);  // Note parentheses around last assignment
```

Or rework it to e.g.

```
c = (x == y ? '=' : x > y ? '>' : '<');
```

Or, which is what I recommend, stop using obfuscated code and use easy, readable code:

```
if (x == y)
    c = '=';
else if (x > y)
    c = '>';
else
    c = '<';
```

<sub>Also note the use of the actual character values, instead of the [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your concern , knowing that's a very simple could and I've already tried the if-else model, My Intention was to try to save a few lines by using the ternary operator.
first I used the literal characters '=' and it gave me an error so i replaced it with the ASCI value and it turned out that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAhmed "Saving lines" is *bad* and lead to obfuscated code that is hard to read, understand and maintain. It won't save you anything in the generated code anyway, all it does is cause you (and other, inclusind yourself in some time) headaches.